# How to addClass into sibling with same class when ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, siblings

I'm want to creating template with ajax.
When button klik it should call the template from sample.html, template structure is more like in var sample, pardon me if its always show error result.

I want to adding class to .contentLoad after ajax success call, so when its success the .contentLoad already in DOM addClass('hidden') except the new .contentLoad I add from ajax.

Is it possible to addClass into sibling with same class when ajax success?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.klik').on('click', function() {
    $('.contentLoad').addClass('hidden');
    chooseClick();
  });
});


var sample = '<div class="contentLoad" style="display: none;">' +
  '<div class="contImg">' +
  '<img class="imgres" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/92957/pexels-photo-92957.jpeg" alt="">' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';

function chooseClick() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'sample.html',
    success: function(temp) {
      $('.load').append(temp).waitForImages(function() {
        $('.loader').hide();
        $('.contentLoad').show();
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      $('.load').prepend('<p>cannot found data</p>');
      $('.loader').hide();
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.loader').show();
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.load {
  position: relative;
  width: 1320px;
  margin: auto;
}

.imgres {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.contentLoad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.loader {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="klik">show</button>
<p class="loader">Loading</p>
<h3>load image here</h3>
<div class="load">
  <div class="contentLoad">
    <div class="contImg">
      <img class="imgres" src="https://now.uiowa.edu/sites/now.uiowa.edu/files/styles/640_wide/public/11_ui_school_of_music.jpg?itok=mxvtE2Am" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: On success you have 2 contentLoad and you want to keep both? but add class to one of them or both?

Comment: yes the content keep increasing, but only class in the DOM addClass('hidden'). so when klik button it will addclass expect new element from ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
var sample = '<div id="newSample" class="contentLoad" style="display: none;">' +
  '<div class="contImg">' +
  '<img class="imgres" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/92957/pexels-photo-92957.jpeg" alt="">' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';

$('.contentLoad:not(#nemSample)').addClass("YourClass")
```

Comment: if I do this way, new element will have class too, I want all sibling will have addclass expect new element I call from ajax

Comment: @mDesto thanks for information, I have updated answer

Comment: I added id into new sample to exclude with its id

Comment: it works, now I have to figure out how make ID static. thanks you brother, it was great help